# Executing view-specific javascript when the view is updated

Tags: html, angularjs

I've been trying to find out how to execute some view-specific javascript code when the model has changed. In the example below, whenever you click the "Say"-button, a new entry will be added to the model, updating the entries-list. The stylesheet limits the entries-list's height to about five entries.

What is the correct way to call something like `scrollLastChatEntryElementIntoView();`? I know how to scroll elements into view, but I can't seem to find any info on how and when I should do this in response to the view being updated? Where am I supposed to declare the script, and when am I supposed to call it?

```
<div class="chat">
   <ol class="entries">
      <li class="entry" ng-repeat="entry in chat.entries">
         <label>{{entry.sender}}</label> {{entry.text}}
      </li>
   </ol>
   <form class="newEntry" ng-submit="chat.newEntry.submit()">
      <input class="text" ng-model="chat.newEntry.text" placeholder="Type to chat"/>
      <span class="button submit" ng-click="chat.newEntry.submit()">Say</span>
   </form>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had a similar situation recently and the way I did it was to create a "auto-scrolling" directive that is listening for the 'DOMSubtreeModified' event on the list element and automatically scrolls down when a new element is added to it.

```
app.directive('autoScrolling', function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        link: function(scope, element, attrs) {

            var el = angular.element(element);

            scope.scrollDown = function(evt) {
                // scroll down:
                el.scrollTop(el.prop('scrollHeight'));
            };

            scope.scrollDown();
            // each time the DOM element of the list changes, 
            // make sure we are scrolled all the way down...
            element.bind('DOMSubtreeModified', scope.scrollDown);
        }
    };  
});
```

and then on your list element

```
<ol auto-scrolling>...
```

[plnkr demo here](http://plnkr.co/edit/BUZinQ?p=preview)

Comment: Thank you Sebastien. Your solution perfectly solves this particular problem.

Comment: +1.  FYI, in the link function, `element` is already a wrapped jQuery element, so you don't have to re-wrap it as an angular element.  In other words, you can use `element` everywhere in the link function -- no need for variable `el`.